# Shiro blows up with database-sessions enabled

Tags: grails, shiro

I'm attempting to secure a grails application using the shiro plugin. I have a simple authentication system in place that works fine with a simple `app-run` in development mode. However, once I run the application in production mode (`grails prod run-app --stacktrace`) Any attempt to login or register throws the error below and refuses to function:

```
| Error 2012-12-03 05:35:15,081 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR databasesession.GormPersisterService  - [Assertion failed] - this String argument must have length; it must not be null or empty
Message: [Assertion failed] - this String argument must have length; it must not be null or empty
   Line | Method
->>  45 | deleteBySessionId in grails.plugin.databasesession.PersistentSessionAttributeValue
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   111 | invalidate        in grails.plugin.databasesession.GormPersisterService
|    90 | proxySession . .  in grails.plugin.databasesession.SessionProxyFilter
|    42 | getSession        in grails.plugin.databasesession.SessionProxyFilter$1
|   147 | getSession . . .  in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroHttpServletRequest
|   188 | getSession        in     ''
|   108 | createSession . . in org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.ServletContainerSessionManager
|    64 | start             in     ''
|   121 | start . . . . . . in org.apache.shiro.mgt.SessionsSecurityManager
|   336 | getSession        in org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject
|   314 | getSession . . .  in     ''
|   182 | mergePrincipals   in org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSubjectDAO
|   163 | saveToSession . . in     ''
|   144 | save              in     ''
|   383 | save . . . . . .  in org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager
|   350 | createSubject     in     ''
|   183 | createSubject . . in     ''
|   283 | login             in     ''
|   257 | login . . . . . . in org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject
|    68 | register          in pfm.SignupController
|   195 | doFilter . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|    63 | doFilter          in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    55 | doFilter . . . .  in org.apache.shiro.grails.SavedRequestFilter
|   449 | executeChain      in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter
|   365 | call . . . . . .  in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1
|    90 | doCall            in org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable
|    83 | call . . . . . .  in     ''
|   380 | execute           in org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject
|   362 | doFilterInternal  in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter
|   125 | doFilter          in org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter
|    51 | doFilterInternal  in grails.plugin.databasesession.SessionProxyFilter
|   886 | runTask           in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run . . . . . . . in     ''
^   680 | run               in java.lang.Thread
```

Since database-session is disabled in development mode and the stacktrace contains `databasesession` I'm assuming that's where the problem lies. I have no idea what's causing it or how to fix it.

Some specs that might be helpful:

```
Grails 2.1.1
compile ":shiro:1.1.4"
```

Let me know if I can supply more information and thanks in advance

Update:
Here is the code that triggers it, in the auth controller:

```
  def signIn = {
        def authToken = new UsernamePasswordToken(params.username, params.password as String)

        // Support for "remember me"
        if (params.rememberMe) {
            authToken.rememberMe = true
        }

        // If a controller redirected to this page, redirect back
        // to it. Otherwise redirect to the root URI.
        def targetUri = params.targetUri ?: "/"

        // Handle requests saved by Shiro filters.
        def savedRequest = WebUtils.getSavedRequest(request)
        if (savedRequest) {
            targetUri = savedRequest.requestURI - request.contextPath
            if (savedRequest.queryString) targetUri = targetUri + '?' + savedRequest.queryString
        }

        try{
            // Perform the actual login. An AuthenticationException
            // will be thrown if the username is unrecognised or the
            // password is incorrect.
            SecurityUtils.subject.login(authToken)

            log.info "Redirecting to '${targetUri}'."
            redirect(uri: targetUri)
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException ex){
            // Authentication failed, so display the appropriate message
            // on the login page.
            log.info "Authentication failure for user '${params.username}'."
            flash.message = message(code: "login.failed")

            // Keep the username and "remember me" setting so that the
            // user doesn't have to enter them again.
            def m = [ username: params.username ]
            if (params.rememberMe) {
                m["rememberMe"] = true
            }

            // Remember the target URI too.
            if (params.targetUri) {
                m["targetUri"] = params.targetUri
            }

            // Now redirect back to the login page.
            redirect(action: "login", params: m)
        }
    }
```

The associated domain classes:

```
class User {
    String username
    String passwordHash
    byte[] passwordSalt
    Manager manager

    static hasMany = [ roles: Role, permissions: String ]

    static constraints = {
        username(nullable: false, blank: false, unique: true)
        manager(nullable: true)
    }
}
```

And finally the security filter:

```
class SecurityFilters {

    def publicActions = [
        signup: ['index','register'],
        auth:['*','*']
    ]

    private boolean findAction(controllerName, actionName){
        def c = publicActions[controllerName]
        return(c)?c.find{(it==actionName||it=='*')}!=null:false
    }

    def filters = {

        all(uri: "/**"){
            before = {
                //Check for public controller/actions
                def isPublic=findAction(controllerName,actionName)

                if(isPublic) return true

                // Ignore direct views (e.g. the default main index page).
                if (!controllerName) return true

                accessControl()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm. It seems that you shiro realm store somethin in the session which the databasesession plugin can't persist to the db.

Check the session and make sure that all objects are serialisable...

Comment: I don't see any issues with it? I added a few snippets of code that might provide information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm. just took a look at the source of the database session plugin. I can't match the linenumbers of your exception with the source. Which version of the plugin are you using?

For me, it looks like the database session plugin misses a sessionId and tries to invalidate the session with an invalid session id.

For me it looks like you've stumbled upon a bug in V1.12 of the plugin: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASESESSION-1

This seems to be fixed already but not released on grails.org .

To get the latest version, download it from https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-database-session/archive/master.zip , unzip it and rename the directory to `grails-database-session`.

open a shell and cd into the `grails-database-session` directory. Execute a `grails package-plugin`. If it complains about the wrong grails version, either switch to the right version or do a `grails upgrade` and a `grails package-plugin` again.

Now cd to your project and do a `grails install-plugin /path/to/grails-database-session/grails-database-session-1.2.zip`.

At least, this just worked for me...

Comment: Ah, that makes sense with my other findings. However, I have trouble confirming you suspicion: it tells me that it is not a valid plugin?

Comment: To elaborate, when trying to use your install-plugin with your link it tells me that it is not a valid plugin? Downloading the zip and running package-plugin doesn't work either yielding "Plugin file not found for plugin project"

Comment: please see my updated answer. I guess you ran into the problem because your generated .zip had the wrong name...

Comment: I followed your instructions and added a compile ":database-session:1.2" to the BuildConfig. It is now correctly loading and listing the plugin for the project. The good news is the error in production mode went away, the bad news is, the behavior didn't change, it still doesn't seem to accept the session. My guess is that I might have forgotten something somewhere (perhaps some additional setup?), but on the other hand it still works flawlessly in development mode. Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: So it seems this question is solved :-) Have you tried to change the debug level of the plugin in order to see what's going on? Have you tried to activate the plugin in development in order to debug it? You write that you need this plugin for running grails on a cluster of servers. On Jelastic, they've simply configured the persistent session feature in tomcat - that work great without the plugin. Only drawback is that everything stored in the session has to be serialisable.

Comment: With debug logging I've gotten a new message that I believe could be the culprit: GRAILS-7799: Subtype 'grails.plugin.databasesession.PersistentSessionService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$de432d7f' of reloadable type grails.plugin.databasesession.PersistentSessionService is not reloadable: may not see changes reloaded in this hierarchy (please comment on that jira) After doing a few lookups I ended up here: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASESESSION-7 So this seems to be an incarnation of that error. Since this is beyond the scope of this post, I'm going to accept the answer. Thanks Ralf!